# C/C++ how to reading const char for UNICODE?

Tags: c, character-encoding

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
void main()
{

    printf("0x%x", '가');
    system("pause");
}
```

The result of this code is "0xB0A1" (CP949)
This is what I want "0xAC00" (UNICODE)

i tried project Configuration Properties character set changed  to UNICODE
but Still not working

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some help. thank you

Comment: ‘Unicode’ is not a character encoding. You can’t have a string or a file encoded in ‘Unicode’ (or ‘UNICODE’, whatever that is).

Comment: `MessageBox(0, L"가", 0, 0)` will do.

Answer (score 2):

`'가'` is a multi-character character constant that doesn't fit in a single
char. You would need to use `wchar_t` defined in [`stddef.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stddef.h.html). See also
[`wchar.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stddef.h.html).

So if you want the unicode value for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>


int main(void)
{

    wchar_t wide = L'가';

    printf("Unicode: 0x%X\n", wide);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
Unicode: 0xAC00
```

However, if you do `wchar_t wide = '가';`, you get a warning and when you run this,
it prints `0xEAB080` which is the UTF8 bytestring.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your problems.